# Kinship terms for older siblings

Tags: kinship-terms

What is the appropriate way to talk about your siblings when you have two older brothers? 二人の兄
If I were to write about them how would I refer to them seperately? Would their names+honorific ie: (さん or ちゃん) be used? Or is there another way to distinguish them in Japanese?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38991/542 this might help. Just convert gender terms.